# ¿Hay algún estudio formal sobre el hecho que se diga "hacen días" en lugar de "hace días"?

Tags: gramática, conjugación, chile, oraciones-impersonales, complemento-directo

¿Hay algún estudio formal sobre el hecho que se diga "hacen días" en lugar de "hace días"?

¿Esto es un error transversal? ¿Tiene que ver con el nivel socioeconómico del hablante? ¿Hay algún estudio que profundice sobre este fenómeno? ¿Ocurre en más de un país?

> Consulta:
> Algunas personas dicen: «Hacen diez días que no veo un policía en el barrio». ¿Es correcta la sintaxis?

> Respuesta:
> Es incorrecta. Cuando el verbo hacer se emplea de manera **impersonal**, va siempre en singular, ya que la «cosa» que «hace» es **complemento directo** y no **sujeto** de la oración. Hace diez días que no veo ningún policía en el barrio. Hace mucho calor. Ayer hacía trece grados.

---

> Esta historia, aunque ficticia, representa nuestra realidad. Seguramente, aquí, en la isla de Puerto Rico, has escuchado “hacen años” miles de veces, sin saber quizás que esta frase es incorrecta. Pero no temas. Hoy te explicaré por qué esta expresión es errónea y te enseñaré la forma recomendada. De esta manera te podrás unir a la caballería de los defensores de la lengua y educar a otros a usar adecuadamente el español.

> En estos casos, “hacer” se expresará siempre “hace” (tercera persona singular). Por eso, la forma correcta es “Hace años que no te veo” y no “Hacen años que no te veo”. De esta forma, mi querido caballero o dama de la lengua española, has aprendido que la forma correcta es “hace años”, “hace meses” y “hace días”, y nunca “hacen años”, etc., en plural. Ahora te toca a ti divulgar este conocimiento para erradicar este error común de nuestras tierras. Así que, defensores del idioma, que sus lenguas se conviertan en espadas y defiendan el buen uso del español en Puerto Rico.

---

https://www.rae.es/duda-linguistica/es-correcto-el-uso-de-hubieron-en-hubieron-muchas-personas-en-la-fiesta
https://www.rae.es/espanol-al-dia/habia-muchas-personas-ha-habido-quejas-hubo-problemas
http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=OeIBjEDjdYZJFCzW

Comment: Usar "hacer" impersonal en plural es tan incorrecto como usar en plural "haber" impersonal. Este segundo error es más común en mi entorno que el primero, inclusive en los medios: *Habían cien personas / *Hubieron muchos problemas.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo que el segundo es mucho más común.

Comment: La RAE dice que se escucha con más intensidad en América, pone como ej. a Colombia y al este y sureste de España http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=OeIBjEDjdYZJFCzW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo normal es encontrar citas como las expuestas, en donde la Rae o persona reputada nos oriente sobre la corrección y las fórmulas más apropiada de utilizar determinadas normas lingüísticas, sin embargo, se atiende menos a dar una explicación del uso de esas locuciones o construcciones y que son habituales por parte de amplias capas de población.

---

La corrección idiomática en Esbozo de una nueva gramática de la lengua española. **Ambrosio Rabanales**

http://www.contrastiva.it/baul_contrastivo/dati/sanvicente/contrastiva/Norma%20est%C3%A1ndar%20y%20variaciones%20en%20espa%C3%B1ol/Rabanales,%20la%20correcci%C3%B3n%20idiom%C3%A1tica%20en%20el%20Esbozo.pdf

---

Dentro de este trabajo sobre la corrección idiomática de Ambrosio Rabanales, en la página 16 del pdf, (262 del general), se encuentra un apartado con el número de párrafo 3.2.3.2. acerca de la utilización como personales de los verbos haber y hacer que es interesante y que quizás conteste a la pregunta. Dejo parte del mismo y el enlace por si deseas consultar o leerlo completo.

---

*Ambrosio Rabanales 1917-2010, nacido en Santiago de Chile, fue doctor en Filología románica, profesor de lingüística teórica y de gramática científica española en la Universidad de Chile y miembro de numero de la Academia Chilena de la Lengua. Fue invitado por varias universidades extranjeras y ha escrito un centenar de trabajos sobre su especialidad*.

> 3.2.3.2. Particularmente interesante -por lo controvertido y a propósito de este criterio- es lo que dice acerca del uso como
> personales de los **verbos haber y hacer**: «Estos verbos tienen entre sus
> varias acepciones la de indicar vagamente existencia o presencia,
> análoga a la que corresponde a los verbos ser' y estar: No hay nadie;
> *Hace mucho frio*. **Esta significación indeterminada** explica que en
> algunas provincias españolas de Levante y en numerosos países
> hispanoamericanos **se interpreten como verbos personales** y se diga
> **Hubieron fiestas**, **Habían muchos soldados**, **Hicieron grandes heladas**,
> **concertando el verbo con su complemento plural, porque no es sentido**
> **como complemento, sino como sujeto**.  Encontramos ejemplos esporádicos
> de esta construcción en textos españoles antiguos:
>
> Algunos ouieron que [...] quisieron disfamar al rey de Navarra (F.
> Pérez de Guzmán). **Hoy hacen**, señor, según mi cuenta, quince años, un
> mes y cuatro días que llego a esta posada una señora en habito de
> peregrina (Cervantes).
>
> Entre los escritores españoles modernos no hallamos ejemplos de este
> uso. Los escritores hispanoamericanos lo evitan generalmente cuando
> hablan por su cuenta, quizá porque los gramáticos lo han censurado
> siempre; **pero en la novela y el teatro**,[**cuando] hacen hablar a sus**
> **personajes en estilo directo** [...] **abundan extraordinariamente los**
> **ejemplos**; v. gr. [...]:
>
> **Hubieron tamales** (M. A. Asturias);  **Hacen días** que está en nuestro
> poder...¿De modo que hacen días? (R. Gallegos). Seria fácil
> multiplicar las citas semejantes...